# Jump to selected page using DataPager Control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, datapager

I have two buttons in My View. One is Download Book and other is View Book. When i click on the View button I navigate to other page and Save the DataPager Current page. and on navigating back i have to show the Previously saved page in DataPager.

Is there any Method or property which i can use to Jump to Selected Page in DataPager Control in Silverlight 5.

I have get the Current Page number using the PageIndex but could not find a way to Navigate back to the same page. Every time The Page is starting From 1 and PageIndex 0.

Any help will be Appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried databinding the pager's PageIndex?

Comment: Yes i tried Databinding on Pagers PageIndex but it goes into the Loop when i try to set the Selected value to pagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make an event like

```
((BooksViewModel)LayoutRoot.DataContext).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(BooksView_PropertyChanged);
```

and call the

```
void BooksView_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "AnyDistinguishedstring")
        {
            Pager.PageIndex = 4; //it will take you to the page 5
        }
    }
```

and From Viewmodel call the

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("AnyDistinguishedstring");
```

will do the trick. :)